# Proving that the intersection of a Sylow p-group with a normal subgroup is also a Sylow p-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, normal-subgroups

An exercise from Dummit and Foote pg. $101$ ex. $9$ asks to show
the following:

> Let $G$ be a group of order $p^{a}n$ where $p$ does not divide $n$ and
>   let $N\unlhd G$ so that $|N|=p^{b}m$ where $p$ does not divide $m$ and $P\leq G$ is of order $p^a$ is a Sylow p-group.
>
> Prove that $|P\cap N|=p^{b}$.

I have seen other posts, but I found only hints or solutions that
uses Sylow theorms (which have yet to be proven in the text).

I tried to use the second isomorphism theorem and I drew the subgroups
lattice, I have also used the fact that $|N\cap P|=p^{r}$ for some
$r$ (using Lagrange) but since I don't know what is $|PN|$ I didn't
manage to find $r$.

Can someone please guide me further ?

Comment: @Arthur - Yes, I have seem to forgot to write it down

Comment: It is  most likely relevant that $N$ is normal, so it probably wouldn't hurt to conjugate things around, see what happens.

Comment: @Arthur - I have used this fact so I could use the second isomorphism theorem

Comment: @Belgi: see my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/641049/115654)

Comment: possible duplicate of [$K$ is a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $S$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Prove that $K \cap S$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641032/k-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-a-finite-group-g-and-s-is-a-sylow-p-subgroup-o)

Comment: Do you know the highest power of $p$ dividing $|PN|$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $N \trianglelefteq G $, $NP$ is  subgroup of $G$ and $[NP:P]=[N:N \cap P]$ (use that $NP/N \cong P/(N \cap P))$. Since $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and $[NP:P]$ divides $[G:P]$, the index $[N:N \cap P]$ is not divisible by $p$. This implies that the $p$-subgroup $N \cap P \in Syl_p(N)$.

Conversely, if $Q \in Syl_p(N)$, then the $p$-subgroup $Q$ is contained in some $P \in Syl_p(G)$ (this is a well-known lemma). Hence $Q \subseteq N \cap P$. But we just showed that $N \cap P \in Syl_p(N)$, whence $Q=N \cap P$. In other words, all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N$ arise by intersecting those of $G$ with $N$.

Comment: Hello!! I read your answer and I got stuck... How do we get that $NP$ is a subgroup of $G$ ?

Comment: In general, if $H \leq G$, and $N \unlhd G$, then $NH$ is a subgroup. This is an easy exercise.

Comment: Ah ok... Thank you!! :-)